# Red fonts in bing search

Tags: security, fonts, colors, bing

When I search using Bing, some results are returned in red fonts. Please help me understand what is this indicating? Below is the snapshot illustrating it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: yea, it's weird, mine doesn't do that: [source](http://puu.sh/719Rq.png)

Comment: it's not a coding problem from bing.com because the entire top row is controlled by 1 color, so images, videos, maps..etc would of changed colors too.

Comment: Does it always do this? Even after a reboot?  Have you tried it with all IE add-on's disabled? How about in Windows' Safe Mode? How about while logged in as another user?

Comment: Reset your IE settings to the default setting.  This will get rid of favorites, ect, backup anything you want to save

Comment: Does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: Rebooted. Cleared history, passwords, caches. Tried in Firefox too. Disabled all extensions. It is still the same.

Comment: I also used different Hotmail account. It is still the same.

Comment: wait, when you say you've tried in firefox, what does that mean? it still does it? If so, it has something to do with your computer, not the browser.

Comment: Input from Ramhound was valuable. The IE reset helped. As soon as I did IE reset, this problem stopped occurring in Firefox as well. Thanks a lot for your input friends.

Comment: @MerinNakarmi Please feel free to add that as an answer to your own question - it's allowed and encouraged (as long as it's also a quality answer that will help future visitors).

Comment: This is happening again. :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input from all friends were helpful especially Ramhound's suggestion helped the most. I wanted to put it as answer here for scared of some people who might just down vote it for no reason.

Well I tested it with different variables, viz. 
1. My work computer which is secured by Office Scan.
2. My personal laptop which uses office's Wi-Fi.
3. My two Hotmail accounts
4. Two browsers, I.E and Firefox. Network admins did not allow Chrome.
5. A colleague's work computer
6. A colleague's Hotmail account.

Following are search results.

1. My work computer displayed results with red fonts for both IE and Firefox. I thought my account was compromised.
2. My laptop in Wi-Fi does not display such weird results even when I use same Hotmail accounts.
3. Then I thought Hotmail account was not compromised, might be our network admin did not want us to use Hotmail accounts for Bing. Other emails are prohibited in our office except in off hours.
4. I made my colleague test in his work computer with his Hotmail accounts and no problem with him.

Following are actions I took.

1. Rebooted the computer.
2. Disabled all extensions.
3. Cleared history, passwords, caches.
4. Tried in private browsing.
5. ***Reset I.E.***

Resetting I.E. did the real work.

Thanks once again to all of you my friends. :)

Comment: This problem is occurring again. :( :(